# Derived Associations with Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I've just started with Entity Framework this week, and am struggling with a few of the concepts.

Right now, I have a database structure that I am struggling to transfer across to entity framework.

I have started with the model first, and have this:

```
------------------        -----------------------
|   Order_Item   |        | Order_FetchableItem |
 ----------------          ---------------------
|   order_id     |        |     order_id        |
|   item_id      |        |     item_id         |
------------------        |     fetch_url       |
                          -----------------------
```

The idea is that orders contain items, and this relation is conveyed in the order_item table. HOWEVER, some (not all) of the items in an order have a URL, so this property needs to be stored too.

I can't get this working in EF, because EF detects Order_Item as a relation, and I can't derive from it.  What's the best alternative for doing this?

I have considered moving the fetch_url field to the Order_Item table, but as it is a wide column, I don't want lots of NULL values in the order_item table.

Thanks, and please excuse the formatting above!

Comment: Can you create a 0..1 relationship between `Order_FetchableItem` and a new table `FetchUrls`?

Comment: I thought this might have been a good call, but EF only seems to be able to do two-way relations, and not three-way ones.  So, this table appears as an entity (not a relation) in EF, and therefore isn't really what I require.  Although it's close!

Comment: You are correct, pretty much everything you do is going to result in a new Entity (outside of properties) especially if you're just working with an EDMX file.  One thing you could do though, is create your `fetch_url` (in code) that simply does the work of reading the navigation property and returning the result.  It's a bit of a hack, but I think that's the best you're going to get when working with an EDMX.

Comment: Argh. This makes it difficult to do things such as differentiating between the items have have fetch URLs, and those that don't, which would be easy if I could use inheritance...

Comment: You might want to consider using "Code First" development with EF, I think it's much more flexible and will probably suit your needs better.